# How to extract complete JSON response data in JMeter?

Tags: json, jmeter

I am new to JMeter and still in learning phase.

I am making a rest call in JMeter. The response data that i receive, i want to use it ***as it is*** in following rest call. Sample of response data that i receive is:

```
{  
   "token":"ab062ad1-0585-4b41-b491-1bd4f6de57da",
   "refreshToken":"5444b837-7f18-4570-a84b-80dac80b393c",
   "expiresBy":"Sat May 02 14:49:06 EDT 2015",
   "mcomroles":[  
      "Super BA Admin",
      "WorkgroupSuperBAUser"
   ],
   "bcomroles":[  
      "Super BA Admin",
      "WorkgroupSuperBAUser"
   ]
}
```

For this i added a Regular Expression Extractor but i do not know what regular expression to give.

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: value of JSONResponse is not getting replaced with its value

Comment: GET http://11.120.111.148:8081/token/validate

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
accessToken: ${JSONResponse}
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Language: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Pragma: no-cache
Host: 11.120.181.148:8081

Comment: Can you post your Jmeter test?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use response as it is , add a beanshell-post processor instead of Regular Expression Extractor.

```
vars.put("JSONResponse", prev.getResponseDataAsString());
```

Now you access it using below statement in the next request.

```
${JSONResponse}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to get the whole response and save it to a JMeter Variable.

As per [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) guide the regular expression which will match everything looks as

`(?s)(^.*)`

The whole extractor configuration should look like:

[image: Regular Expression whole body]

`${response}` variable will hold parent sampler response data.